# Apache Airflow install Postgress as Backend DB - ERROR

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I am trying to install Postgres as a backend DB instead of Sqllite. I followed these steps but ran into an error. can someone help, please?

Steps followed:

1. activated virtual env.
2. installed postgreSQL
   `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
3. created psql object with:
   `sudo -u postgres psql`

4.create the user and database for the airflow
`CREATE USER **** PASSWORD '****';`
`postgres=# CREATE DATABASE airflow;`
`postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO newt;`

5. updated postgresql.conf with `listen_addresses= '*'`
6. added pg_hba.conf with
   `host db-name user-name ip-address trust`
7. updated airflow.cfg file with
   `sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user-name:password@localhost:5432/db-name`
8. restarted airflow db.

`airflow resetdb`

After the 8th steps I got below error, what am i doing wrong here? any advise

Error message

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused`
`Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting`
`TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`
`could not connect to server: Connection refused`
`Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting`
`TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Answer (score 0):

After changing the `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` you have to tell PostreSQL that a change has been made. You can do it by either restarting the database, e.g. on Ubuntu

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```

... or by executing the function `pg_reload_conf`

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf():
```

In case client and database are in different machines, make sure that there is no firewall between them messing things up.

**Unrelated note**: Also keep in mind that setting a connection to `trust` in the pg_hba.conf means that no password is required. For testing purposes more than legit but quite dangerous if forgotten in production ;)